# Is it Possible to Run a Python Code Forever?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I have coded a Python Script for Twitter Automation using Tweepy. Now, when i run on my own Linux Machine as `python file.py` The file runs successfully and it keeps on running because i have specified repeated Tasks inside the Script and I also don't want to stop the script either. But as it is on my Local Machine, the script might get stopped when my Internet Connection is off or at Night. So i couldn't keep running the Script Whole day on my PC..

So is there any way or website or Method where i could deploy my Script and make it Execute forever there ? I have heard about CRON JOBS before in Cpanel which can Help repeated Tasks but here in my case i want to keep running my Script on the Machine till i don't close the script .

Are their any such solutions. Because most of twitter bots i see are running forever, meaning their Script is getting executed somewhere 24x7 . This is what i want to know, How is that Task possible?

Comment: You don't run it on your own PC, you run it on some cloud service (Cloud Foundry, Python Anywhere, Heroku, ...)

Comment: You might want to check out something like Amazon EC2.

Comment: +Vincent Russo & +jonrsharpe Yes i will try looking up there :) Thanks for advice

Comment: You can't run Python code forever. Eventually, the universe will collapse or something.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jon and Vincent, it's better to run the code from a cloud service. But either way, I think what you're looking for is what to put into the terminal to run the code even after you close the terminal. This is what worked for me:

```
nohup python code.py &
```

Comment: if close ssh and shutdown my local pc where im accessing the cloud service [digital ocean or google cloud] , will it shtill run ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a systemd `.service` file, which can have the added benefit of:

- logging (compressed logs at a central place, or over network to a log server)
- disallowing access to `/tmp` and `/home`-directories
- restarting the service if it fails
- starting the service at boot
- setting capabilities (ref `setcap`/`getcap`), disallowing file access if the process only needs network access, for instance